# Creating XML data source file in SSIS

Tags: xml, ssis

I need to transfer all data from a OLEDB source to XML file and there is huge amt of data in each table.
I tried it using variable and writing a variable to txt file but for this case there are hundreds of columns in table with hundreds of records, so cant use variable.

Comment: I hope my problem statement is clear to understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through the below link.

http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2010/12/flexible-xml-destination.html